# How to use AWS sdk in PHP for file operations for s3 and ec2?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I stuck up in a situation where I need to write files to S3 and EC2 as well.

The below code is perfectly working to write files to S3, but dont know how to write to EC2.

```
    <?php

    if(file_exists('aws-autoloader.php')){

        require 'aws-autoloader.php';
    }else{

        die( 'File does not exist');
    }

    define('AWS_KEY','*****');
    define('AWS_SECRET','********');

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

    $credentials = new Credentials(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET);

    $client = new S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'ap-southeast-1',
        'credentials' => $credentials
    ]);

    $client->registerStreamWrapper();

    file_put_contents('s3://mybucket/abc/a.txt', 'test');

    @chmod('/var/app/current', 0755);

//Not able to write the content to EC2 instance
    @file_put_contents('/var/app/current/b.txt', 'test');
    @file_put_contents('file://var/app/current/b.txt', 'test');
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you have to write files to another instance? Or to a local instance? If it's local, does your app have permissions to write to `/var/app...`?

Comment: I am really sorry, Its the problem with the permissions

Answer (score 0):

It works without any problem with below code, if the application is having write permission.

```
    file_put_contents('/var/app/current/b.txt', 'test');
or
    file_put_contents('file:///var/app/current/b.txt', 'test');
```